# the perimeter of a shape combined of several shapes

Tags: python, algorithm, svg

I have several svg paths, and I'd like to get the outmost path of the combined shape. For instance for the following paths:

```
<path d="M 90 10 L 50 50 L 50 10 z"/>
<path d="M 130 50 L 130 90 L 90 90 z"/>
<path d="M 50 50 L 90 10 L 90 50 L 70 70 z"/>
<path d="M 10 90 L 10 50 L 50 50 L 70 70 L 50 90 z"/>
<path d="M 70 110 L 70 130 L 50 130 L 50 90 z"/>
<path d="M 90 50 L 130 50 L 70 110 L 50 90 z"/>
<path d="M 90 90 L 90 130 L 70 130 L 70 110 z"/>
```

I'd like to get

```
<path d="M 50 10 L 90 10 L 90 50 L 130 50 L 130 90 L 90 90 L 90 130 L 50 130 L 50 90 L 10 90 L 10 50 L 50 50 z"/>
```

What would be a good algorithm to get to this path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150766/union-of-many-more-than-two-polygons-without-holes

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Not exactly a duplicate, that question was about polygons. I believe SVG paths are more general than polygonal chains.

Comment: OPs paths were all effectively polygons.  I took a chance that that was good enough for him/her.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I combine complex polygons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667748/how-do-i-combine-complex-polygons)